# install4j how to parse json in a form component

Tags: install4j

I'm trying to parse json in an action script for a form component.

I tried to:

`import javax.json.JsonObject;`

And get the following on a test compile:

```
Failed to compile script
1. ERROR in /private/var/folders/3t/l3dvn7tx1j76wsx17xfjcpww0000gn/T/script10053200329813627000.java.dir/code/Completion.java (at line 1)
    import javax.json.JsonObject;
The import javax.json cannot be resolved
```

How do I achieve the equivalent of this import so I can parse json? I started going down the rabbit hole of create a JMOD for javax.json but that's starting to seem like the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

The package `javax.json` is not part of the JRE, but a JEE 7 API. You can download the JAR file from

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api/1.1.4

and add it on the "Installer->Screens & Actions->Custom code" step. Then the class will be available in all scripts.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a newbie and that helped me get over a hurdle.